# Warning Pass-by-Value?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am fairly new to Objective-C and whilst running the Clang static analyser this section of code gave me the following error

```
warning: Pass-by-value argument in message expression is undefined
[artistCollection removeObject:removeArtist];
```

Can anyone cast any light on this warning for me?

```
case 6:
    NSLog(@"(*) - First Name:");
    scanf("%s", userFirName);
    objFirName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:userFirName];
    for(eachArtist in artistCollection) {
        if([[eachArtist firName] isEqualToString: objFirName]) {
            removeArtist = eachArtist;
        }
    }
    [artistCollection removeObject:removeArtist];
    [objFirName release], objFirName = nil;
    break;
```

gary

Comment: What and where are your definitions for `removeArtist` and `eachArtist`?

Comment: Actually, are you initializing `removeArtist` as `nil`? If not, and it's not set in the loop, it will be undefined when you call `removeObject:`.

Comment: could you describe the logic of this? What are you trying to do (in plain english or pseudo-code, not obj-c code)?

Comment: “`case 6:`” Don't do this. Make an enumeration, and use those constants in your case labels. That will make your code much, much clearer, and you can turn on a warning that will trip if you fail to use all of the enumerated constants (i.e., if you fail to cover all cases).

Comment: `[objFirName release], objFirName = nil;` Don't do this, either. You should be getting a warning for this expression, since the two sides of it are of mixed types (the `release` message returns `void`, while the assignment of an `id` evaluates to `id`). You should split the comma expression into two statements by replacing the comma operator with a semicolon. I honestly can't think of a good reason to use the comma operator.

Comment: Thank you, @peter I have updated my code to use enum, also in future I will split the release and the assign to nil across two statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you never get a match on that `if` inside your loop (because `userFirName` isn't in your collection), `removeArtist` will never get assigned a value.  Assign it a value before starting the loop (`nil`, probably), and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, a silly mistake, still trying to get to grips with this. Two questions, it is my understand that it is bad to delete from within  the for loop, which is why I delete the object outside. Am I right in thinking that? Finally, should I have a [removeArtist release] in there? looking at it now it feels like I do.

Comment: Yes, if you try to modify the array while you're in the loop, you'll get an exception, according to the docs.

I don't know if you need a `[removeArtist release]` in there; the collection will release it when you call `removeObject:`, so you don't need to do it yourself unless you retained it elsewhere for some reason (I would expect probably not).

Comment: The aforementioned document snippet: "Enumeration is 'safe'—the enumerator has a mutation guard so that if you attempt to modify the collection during enumeration, an exception is raised." - http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18-SW1